# Passing reference to object in callback function to std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, stdthread

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
void commands_conn_handler(int socket, RPiServer& server) {
  // Not important code about handling connection
}

class RPiServer {
public:
  void Accept(void Accept(void (*acceped_conn_handler)(int, RPiServer&)) {
    // (...)
    int remote_socket = 0; // Doesn't matter - example.
    std::thread conn_handler_thread(acceped_conn_handler, remote_socket, *this);
    conn_handler_thread.join();
  }
};

int main() {
  RPiServer commands_server();
  commands_server.Accept(commands_conn_handler);
}
```

And when I try to build this, there are some errors:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/thread:39:0,
>                    from src/rpi_server/rpiserver.cpp:11:
>   /usr/include/c++/6/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple’:
>   /usr/include/c++/6/thread:138:26:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*&)(int, RPiServer&); _Args = {int&, RPiServer&}]’
>   src/rpi_server/rpiserver.cpp:89:79:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/6/functional:1365:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of’
>          typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
>                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
>   /usr/include/c++/6/functional:1386:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of’
>            _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
>            ^~~~~~~~~
>   Makefile:29: recipe for target 'build/rpi_server/rpiserver.o' failed

When I change thread function in following way (remove reference to object):

```
void commands_conn_handler(int socket) {
  // Not important code about handling connection
}

class RPiServer {
public:
  void Accept(void (*acceped_conn_handler)(int)) {
    // (...)
    int remote_socket = 0; // Doesn't matter - example.
    std::thread conn_handler_thread(acceped_conn_handler, remote_socket);
    conn_handler_thread.join();
  }
};

int main() {
  RPiServer commands_server();
  commands_server.Accept(commands_conn_handler);
}
```

Everything builds perfectly fine. What I'm doing wrong when I'm passing reference as parameter to thread function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here you have a working example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
class RPiServer;

void commands_conn_handler(int socket, RPiServer &server) {
    // Not important code about handling connection
}

class RPiServer {
public:
    void Accept(void (*acceped_conn_handler)(int, RPiServer&)) {
        // (...)
        int remote_socket = 0; // Doesn't matter - example.
        std::thread conn_handler_thread(acceped_conn_handler, remote_socket, std::ref(*this));
        conn_handler_thread.join();
    }
};

int main() {
    RPiServer commands_server;
    commands_server.Accept(commands_conn_handler);
}
```

The error you was getting was because you were not providing correct type for the constructor of `conn_handler_thread`. To explicitly get a reference to an object (which you need to do here), use a [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) function.

*P.S.:* Also you copy pasted your code example wrong, duplicating the `void Accept` part. You also had a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) error in `main()`.

Comment: The compiler is deducing the arguments of the `template< class Function, class... Args > explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args )` constructor as `void(*)(int,RPiServer&),int,RPiServer)`, which will not work as you cannot bind the RPiServer value to the non-const lvalue reference. You cannot pass template parameters to a constructor, so you need to explicitly specify `std::ref` on `*this`. Alternatively, making the `RPiServer&` argument const compiles as well, but you might create a temporary.